# How to secure a website that uses session-state to store data from a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, session, session-state

I am using ASP.NET using WebForm using LINQ to read data from xml which I get as a response from a web-service. Using that data to display on webpage using search functionality means users will be able to search for collections. (using sessions to store and access data when the user searches for any keyword.)

What factors should I take to ensure that my application is secure?

Comment: What are your security requirements?  Do you want to secure the web service, session state, regular web requests etc?  There are books written about your question.

Comment: Yeah it is open ended question! I want to secure in terms of session state.

Comment: 'In terms of session state'?  Would you like to encrypt session state data in a database, in memory or in the state server?  Are you dealing with recipes or medical records?  Is everything going over SSL?  Some detail would help to provide a good answer.

Comment: @dtryon I am storing the search results for a user in a session and accessing it as per needs. So should I encrypt data in memory? the records are basically the collections of the museum. nothing is going over SSL!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really want to help, but I'm still finding the question a bit vague.  It sounds like the first thing to do is read up on common exploits and then see how best you can secure your site.  Security is always a trade-off and therefore always matches requirements.  If the data is publicly available (like museum data), then perhaps you don't need any security at all!  On the other hand, if you are dealing with PCI level-1 credit card data, you may have to encrypt at rest everywhere (for example).

However, the best reference for the exploits you need to look out for is [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project).  They cover web exploits very well and publish a 'top ten' list every year of the ways applications are most exploited.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @dtryon for your support. I will go through the resource. :D

Answer (score 1):

Here is an article about [Session Security in ASP.Net](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article730-session-security-in-aspnet.aspx). Hope you find this useful.